# Autofac load dependencies from referenced and non referenced assemblies

Tags: c#, autofac, webapi2, autofac-module

I have seen many question that ask how to load all referenced assemblies even if not directly used, but I would like to take that a step further.  I am building a service and interface that can be extended, the intention is that I could extend the Sender/Receiver with additional types, for example: the interface is responsible for sending SMS messages and can have different adapters, say I have two different applications that want to use SMS, each would have its own implementation of an `ISmsAdapter` and `ISmsReplyAdapter`, the assemblies may not necessarily be referenced by the Service (the application comprises of a Windows Service and a WebAPI service to receive replies).

What I would like to be able to do is not just register my autofac modules that are in referenced assemblies, but also register modules in assemblies that are in say a specific folder such as /bin/plugins or something similar

I have not been able to find anything that relates to this other than `Caliburn.Micro` which has a `DirectoryCatalog` which does something similar to what I want

Does anyone know how I might be able to achieve this with Autofac please?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an Autofac question so much as a reflection question. Autofac doesn't care how you load assemblies.

Load your assemblies through reflection using something like [Assembly.LoadFrom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx) and then use the assembly scanning in Autofac or continue using reflection to manually locate certain types in the assemblies (eg types that inherit from module, types with a certain naming convention, types that implement a certain interface, etc.) and register the types individually in a for-loop.